# .htaccess RewriteRule url with numbers ONLY

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like me site to load php files even if I dont add the .php
Example:

```
domain.com/test
```

Will load domain.com/test.php
I did it with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now I want url with ONLY numbers to be redirected to homepage with the number storing in $_GET['sponsor']
I did it with:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+) index.php?sponsor=$1
```

So
Example:
domain.com/888
Will load domain.com/index.php and $_GET['sponsor']=888

The problem is that any url with number give me and error,
For example
domain.com/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff

How can I change the htaccess so ONLY numbers will be redirected, any other real file with number in his filename will keep loading as is ?

Comment: What's the difference between `^(.*)$` and just `([0-9]+)` as placeholder?

Comment: @mario I didn't understand what you mean. ([0-9]+) is just for numbers.

Comment: But didn't you notice the meta characters around the parens?

Comment: I wouldn't spend your time ifI saw what is wrong. Can you help and show?

Comment: See the second duplicate link for the exact pattern. Or the third reference for a more in-depth introduction on how rewriterules and patterns work.